# Utilizing delegate pattern for matrices

Tags: java, oop, generics, delegates

I implemented a delegate pattern to hide away the linear algebra libraries I wanted to benchmark, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097206/abstracting-away-matrix-library-dependency), see:

```
public interface Matrix<M> {

    /**
     * Cols or this matrix
     *
     * @return columns
     */
    int rows();

    /**
     * Rows of this matrix
     *
     * @return rows
     */
    int cols();

    /**
     * Matrix multiplication, should throw if cols and rows do not match.
     * Contract is This X in, i.e. this_rows*this_cols X in_cols*in_rows
     *
     * @param otherMatrix right operand
     * @return new matrix multiplied
     */
    M multiply(M otherMatrix);

    /**
     * Multiply each element with this scalar
     *
     * @param scalar to multiply with
     * @return scaled with scalar
     */
    M multiply(double scalar);

    /**
     * Add in to this matrix
     *
     * @param in right operand
     * @return this + in
     */
    M add(M in);

    /**
     * Add in to all elements of this.
     *
     * @param in scalar operand
     * @return this.map(e - > e + in)
     */
    M add(double in);

    /**
     * Subtract in from all elements of this
     *
     * @param in scalar operand
     * @return this.map(e - > e - in);
     */
    M subtract(double in);

    /**
     * Substract in from this matrix
     *
     * @param in right operand
     * @return this[i][j] -= in[i][j]
     */
    M subtract(M in);

    /**
     * Divide all elements by in
     *
     * @param in scalar operand
     * @return in.map(e - > e / in);
     */
    M divide(double in);

    /**
     * Map this matrix to a double, useful for reduce or trace implementations
     *
     * @param mapping f: This -> double
     * @return a double value
     */
    double map(Function<M, Double> mapping);

    /**
     * Map each element with this function
     *
     * @param mapping f: Double -> Double each element
     * @return this.map(e - > mapping ( e));
     */
    M mapElements(Function<Double, Double> mapping);

    /**
     * Sum this matrix over all entries.
     *
     * @return sum of this
     */
    double sum();

    /**
     * Max of this matrix over all entries.
     *
     * @return max of this
     */
    double max();

    /**
     * Index along a column of max, should only be used for vectors.
     *
     * @return index of max
     */
    int argMax();

    /**
     * Transpose this matrix.
     *
     * @return transpose.
     */
    M transpose();

    enum MatrixType {
        VECTOR, SQUARE
    }
}
```

with this class:

```
public class UJMPMatrix implements Matrix<UJMPMatrix> {
    
    private org.ujmp.core.Matrix delegate;        

    public UJMPMatrix(UJMPMatrix in) { this.delegate = in.delegate; }
    public UJMPMatrix(org.ujmp.core.Matrix in) { this.delegate = in; }
   
    public int rows() {
        return (int) this.delegate.getRowCount();
    }

    public int cols() {
        return (int) this.delegate.getColumnCount();
    }

    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix multiply(UJMPMatrix otherMatrix) {
        return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.mtimes(otherMatrix.delegate));
    }


    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix multiply(double scalar) {
        return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.times(scalar));
    }

    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix add(UJMPMatrix in) {
        return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.plus(in.delegate));
    }

    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix add(double in) {
        return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.plus(in));
    }

    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix subtract(double in) {
        return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.minus(in));
    }

    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix subtract(UJMPMatrix in) {
        return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.minus(in.delegate));
    }

    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix divide(double in) {
        return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.divide(in));
    }

    @Override
    public double map(Function<UJMPMatrix, Double> mapping) {
        return mapping.apply(this);
    }

    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix mapElements(Function<Double, Double> mapping) {
        double[][] elements = this.delegate.toDoubleArray();
        double[][] out = new double[elements.length][elements[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < elements[0].length; i++) {
                out[i][j] = mapping.apply(elements[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return new UJMPMatrix(out, rows(), cols());
    }

    @Override
    public double sum() {
        return this.delegate.getValueSum();
    }

    @Override
    public double max() {
        return this.delegate.max(Calculation.Ret.NEW, 0).doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix transpose() {
        return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.transpose());
    }

    @Override
    public int argMax() {
        double[] array = this.delegate.toDoubleArray()[0];
        int argMax = -1;
        double best = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > best) {
                best = array[i];
                argMax = i;
            }
        }

        return argMax;

    }
}
```

However, when I want to use this abstraction, Java tells me that I cannot use any of these methods, because of the wildcard I need (?) to use to declare these matrices:

```
 private void feedForward(final Matrix<? extends Matrix<?>> starter, final List<Matrix<? extends Matrix<?>>> actives) {
        Matrix<? extends Matrix<?>> toPredict = starter;

        actives.add(toPredict);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.totalLayers - 1; i++) {
            final Matrix<? extends Matrix<?>> x = this.weights[i].multiply(toPredict).add(this.biases[i]);
            // Weights and Biases are also Matrix<? extends Matrix<?>>[].
            // error: cannot resolve method multiply(Matrix<capture ? extends Matrix<?>>)
            toPredict = this.functions[i + 1].function(x);
            actives.add(toPredict);
        }
    }
```

Note: In the constructor of the Neural Network I let the caller decide what type of Matrix they want by a simple enum { OJ_ALGO, UJMP }, and call the Factory I implemented to intialise those matrices. The fields of the neural network look like this:

```
// Weights and biases of the network
private volatile Matrix<? extends Matrix<?>>[] weights;
private volatile Matrix<? extends Matrix<?>>[] biases;
private volatile Matrix<? extends Matrix<?>>[] dW;
private volatile Matrix<? extends Matrix<?>>[] dB;
```

Question: How do I declare, initialise and utilise the Matrix abstraction I implemented in this neural network library?

Answer (score 0):

Your `feedForward` method needs a generic type to signify that both arguments must be of the same type (note the `<M>` before void) :

```
private <M> void feedForward(final Matrix<M> starter, final List<M> actives) {
```

And likewise your neural network class should declare the type of matrices it is using (assuming you don't want to use different implementations at the same time):

```
public class NeuralNetwork<M> {
    private volatile Matrix<M>[] weights;
    private volatile Matrix<M>[] biases;
    private volatile Matrix<M>[] dW;
    private volatile Matrix<M>[] dB;
```

As a side note, I'm not sure why these are declared as volatile.

Your interface should look like this:

```
public interface Matrix<M> {
    Matrix<M> multiply(Matrix<M> otherMatrix);
    M delegate();
```

And your implementation:

```
public class UJMPMatrix implements Matrix<org.ujmp.core.Matrix> {
    
    private org.ujmp.core.Matrix delegate; 

    @Override
    public UJMPMatrix  multiply(Matrix<org.ujmp.core.Matrix> otherMatrix) {
        return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.mtimes(otherMatrix.delegate()));
    }

    @Override
    public org.ujmp.core.Matrix delegate() {
        return delegate();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, again. When I implement the Matrix interface, it gets clunky. I could not implement it the way in the post, I had to change the `Matrix<M>`interface to instad of returning `M`return `Matrix<M>`for all Matrix methods, like this: `Matrix<M> add(Matrix<M> other);`. This result in me having to implement a `delegate()` method which returns the type of the Matrix, to then access the actual delegate like so: `Matrix<UJMPMatrix> add(Matrix<UJMPMatrix> other) { return new UJMPMatrix(this.delegate.add(other.delegate().delegate)); }`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: UJMPMatrix shoud implement `Matrix<org.ujmp.core.Matrix>` see my edited answer